# add field to foregin key table and query with eloquent

Tags: laravel, key, eloquent

I've 2 Models, let's say: `Cart` and `Product`.

`Cart` has many `Product`. `Product` belongs to `Cart`

3 tables `cart`, `product`, `cart_product` (`id`, `cart_id`, `product_id`)

I insert another field to `cart_product`, ex: (`id`, `cart_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`).

When I attach a `Product` to a `Cart` how can I query the relation to insert a quantity?

Answer (score 0):

self answer:

```
$cart->products()->attach($p, array('blablabla', 'blablabla'));
```